# Yii2 disable debug mode but allow sending logs via email

Tags: php, logging, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I have configured error logs to be sent via email by configuring a email target as shown [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html#log-targets). Everything works fine.
The thing is that if I disable debug mode (by setting the constant YII_DEBUG to false) the logs are not being sent anymore.

I'd still like to hide error messages in production but I also want to be notified if any user in production mode get any error. Is there any way to do so?

Edit: it was my configuration fault, I was enabling only the frontend logger.

```
if(Yii::$app->id == 'app-frontend') {
    Yii::$app->log->targets['emailFrontend']->enabled = SETTING_EMAIL_LOG_FRONTEND;
}
else if(Yii::$app->id == 'app-backend'){
    Yii::$app->log->targets['emailBackend']->enabled = SETTING_EMAIL_LOG_BACKEND;
}
```

Comment: Logging and sending messages is not affected by YII_DEBUG by default. Look for your settings, for example param 'enable' in target's config.

Comment: I will try to see but I'm quite sure it's because of YII_DEBUG. If it's not enabled logs are not sent. I'm already using the parameter enabled and right now is enabled.

Comment: Search in your project to find `YII_DEBUG` usage, excluding `vendor` folder.

Comment: Sorry, it was indeed my bad. I was overriding target configuration for backend logger.

Comment: Anyway is it ok to configure targets in the beforeAction of controllers? Or there is a better way to do so? (I have a base controller that is extended by all my controllers)

Comment: create a new question for this ;)

Comment: @Fabrizio if you are trying to write logs then you should go for the `afterAction()` rather than `beforeAction()` to make the page loads faster.